# The jvm crashed looks like it was caused by JIT

Tags: jvm

I wrote a server application in Java 8 but occasionally crashes.
running it with

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

gdb $JAVA_HOME/bin/java core.53164

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f80df3aa493 in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) ()
   from /data/disk01/hh_process_prod_cube_mpp/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#1  0x00007f80def60ed2 in CompileQueue::get() () from /data/disk01/hh_process_prod_cube_mpp/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007f80def6977b in CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop() ()
   from /data/disk01/hh_process_prod_cube_mpp/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007f80df55d40b in JavaThread::thread_main_inner() ()
   from /data/disk01/hh_process_prod_cube_mpp/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007f80df55d711 in JavaThread::run() () from /data/disk01/hh_process_prod_cube_mpp/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007f80df3eb2e2 in java_start(Thread*) () from /data/disk01/hh_process_prod_cube_mpp/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x00007f80e02bcdd5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x00007f80dfbc9ead in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Download a newer version first (newer than 1.8, if possible, or at least jdk 8u301) and try on there. You're unlikely to get much help here unless you can post reproducible code (and even then not likely, since it's likely a bug in the jdk).

Comment: When the JVM crashes, it produces the crash dump `hs_err_pid.log`, so show the entire dump file.

Comment: After jvm crashes, hs_err_pid.log is not generated, but there is a core.pid file